# How to fix null sending message to a Handler on a dead thread warning?

Tags: android

I have a thread using handler and messages to send data to the activity. Everything work fine except when the activity is paused :

```
null sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
java.lang.RuntimeException: null sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
    at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:196)
    at android.os.Looper.quit(Looper.java:173)
    at pocket.net.ComD.stopConnection(ComD.java:154)
    at pocket.net.ComD.finalize(ComD.java:184)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

In my activity , i have the following code which lets me close all the network connection opened by the thread :

```
public void onPause() 
{
    if(this.myThread != null) {
        this.myThread.stopConnection();
    }
}
```

In my Thread :

```
public void run()
{
    this.setName("MessagesThread");
    if(this.initSocket())
    {

            Looper.prepare();
            this.threadHandler = initHandler();
            Looper.loop();
    }
    else
    {
        this.timeout();
    }
}

public void stopConnection()
{
    if(this.threadHandler != null) {
        this.threadHandler.removeMessages(ALIVE); // Remove a delayed message   
        this.threadHandler.getLooper().quit(); // Warning
    }
    this.connected = false;
    if(this.client != null) {
        this.client.close();
    }
}

private Handler initHandler()
{
    return new Handler() {

        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            switch(msg.what)
            {
                //Handling messages
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i receive the warning "null sending message to a Handler on a dead thread" is that the activity trying to send a message to the thread or the oppposite ?

How can i fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: I thought you wanted to send data from the worker thread to the activity (UI thread)? If so, shouldn't the `Handler` be in the `Activity` while the worker thread `sendMessage` to it? Sorry if I misunderstood your logic

Comment: The worker thread send data to the activity indeed. But the activity ask this data (and other stuff) to the worker thread. So both of them have handler and messages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting the error as Looper.quit() has already been called.

> So the message queue is basically unusable after Looper.quit() has been called the first time, as it enqueues a Message with a null target, which is the magical identifier for the message queue to stop enqueuing and appear "dead".

You need to do something like:

```
private boolean stoppedFlag= false;
public void stopConnection()
{
    if(this.threadHandler != null) {
        this.threadHandler.removeMessages(ALIVE); // Remove a delayed message   
        if(!stoppedFlag){
            this.threadHandler.getLooper().quit(); // Warning
            stopFlag = true;
        }
    }
    this.connected = false;
    if(this.client != null) {
        this.client.close();
    }
}
```

To stop quit() being called multiple times

[Ref Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#quit%28%29)

[Ref Looper SOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643006/calling-looper-more-than-once-causes-sending-message-to-a-handler-on-a-dead-thre/4254952#4254952)